# GitX - Disabled View Buttons

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitx

My GitX works fine for any main repo I might be working with. However, when my main repo contains submodules and I open GitX at the submodule directory, the 'View' buttons are disabled. This is preventing me from accessing the 'Commit View' where I can stage and commit changes through GitX.

Anyone know why GitX might be preventing me from using the 'View' buttons?

Comment: This won't answer your question, but I seriously suggest you switch to [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (Free). It has a very similar interface, but is much more stable and full featured.

Comment: Thanks for the SourceTree recc. I now use it and love it. Sooo much nicer.

Answer (score -1):

You are using an out of date version of GitX. Use this actively maintained version: https://rowanj.github.io/gitx/

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Answer (score -2):

I have this issue too. Which version of git are you using?

I had trouble with GitX(L) and crashes when opening a submodule that had been initialised with Git v1.8. It seems that whilst GitX will open it, viewing modified files is not available. The issue was supposed to be fixed in GitX though around 8 months ago with a move to updated libgit2.

Comment: 'Me too!' answers are not acceptable, particularly when there's nothing else to them.